# Unable to recover from errors in Conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit

I am trying to understand how to catch errors thrown within conduits. I believed that by applying `catchC` on a conduit, I could produce a new conduit that would rerun in the event of a faillure.

In the example below we have a source that, depending on a boolean value, will throw an custom dummy exception. Initially the value of that boolean leads to that exception being thrown, however the handler inside `catchC` produces a new conduit that should exhibit the opposite behaviour (yielding the numbers from 1 to 10)

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

module Main where

import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Exception
import Data.Typeable

data MyException = MyException String
    deriving (Show, Typeable)

instance Exception MyException where

listAsStream :: Bool -> Source IO Int
listAsStream val =  if val then CL.sourceList [1..10] else throw $ MyException "Value"

conduitWhatever :: Sink Int IO ()
conduitWhatever = awaitForever $ liftIO . print

main :: IO ()
main = catchC (listAsStream False) handler $$ conduitWhatever

handler :: MyException -> Source IO Int
handler _= catchC (listAsStream True) handler
```

I am pretty sure I have misunderstood how `catchC` works. Could anyone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your usage of `catchC` is correct; the problem is the usage of `throw`, which introduces an imprecise exception instead of a proper `IO` exception. If you instead use:

```
liftIO $ throwIO $ MyException "Value"
```

your program works as expected.